# speed up prime number generating?

Tags: python

This program generates prime numbers . It works well but I want to speed it up as it takes quite a while for generating the all the prime numbers

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#intgr = int(raw_input ("Please enter your number: "))
intgr = 50000

for i in range (2, intgr+1):
    j = 2
    while j<i:
        if (i%j) == 0:
            break
        j += 1
    if j == i:
        #print "prime", i
        pass #print "prime", i
print "done"
```

it takes about 15 seconds to run right now i would like to decrease that time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes

Comment: First off, I'm assuming python2, since the print statement at the end is only valid in python2, I'd use xrange() instead of range().

Comment: You should look up algorithms created to generate prime numbers, for example the sieve of eratosthenes

Comment: Your condition should be `while j <= sqrt(i)` (clearly I'm not familiar with python syntax). The `if` after that, too.

Comment: This is much slower than using an O(n) sieve.

Answer (score -1):

Generating prime numbers is inherently slow. The algorithm you implemented is known as Trial Division and is one of the slowest ways to generate primes. There are other algorithms which are much faster, for example the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I suggest you do some more research about better algorithms.

Comment: According to wikipedia, it's not the fastest, but the simplest. I'm not really sure this answer needs to be more than a comment, btw.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?